# Multiplying array indexes in PHP with array_reduce

Tags: php, array-reduce

Why does the `array_reduce()` method work differently when adding and multiplying? When I *add* the array values below, the code produces the expected result: **15**. But when I *multiply*, it returns: **0**. Same code... The only difference is that the `+` sign is switched for the `*` sign.

```
  function sum($arr){
        print_r(array_reduce($arr, function($a, $b){return $a + $b;}));
    }

    function multiply($arr){
        print_r(array_reduce($arr, function($a, $b){return $a * $b;}));
    }

    sum(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)); // 15
    multiply(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)); // 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to documentation, you might wanna try

```
function multiply($arr){
        print_r(array_reduce($arr, function($a, $b){return $a * $b;},1));
}
```

Here is a quote from [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php#78695) discussion:

> The first parameter to the callback is an accumulator where the result-in-progress is effectively assembled. If you supply an $initial value the accumulator starts out with that value, otherwise it starts out null.

Comment: Beat me to it by 20 seconds

Comment: Here's a link to the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Comment: @shmuli becausee you need to set an initial value, it seems $a in the first round is 0 so everything is multiplied by 0

Comment: @shmuli [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php#78695) is the elaborate discussion about the "why", and Hakem, you may provide an appropriate quote of that note in your answer, for the future visitors.